# Python 2/3 write only diff to file

Tags: python, yaml, diff

I have a problem with two constraints that could easily be solved by lifting one or the other, however, I'd like to see if there's a solution.

note: for the below, I use dictionary/file/database pretty interchangeably

I have a large-ish dictionary that I'm storing to a YAML file (149K) which works as a readable database for audio tags.

The program which uses the databse needs to make updates to it while it is running. Currently, this involves making the change in memory then writing the entirety to file, then running a second program which updates some values based on database contents, then reading it back into memory. The problem is that this is slow (and ugly) and I want something faster.

I know this could be solved by using a "real" relational db engine like SQLite, *but* I want the db to be readable, in text.

Another solution might be to only operate in memory and then encase the program in a try/catch and dump the dictionary to disk if the program terminates prematurely. But this incurs checking and testing that I don't want to bother with. Ideally I could make the changes asynchronously and on-demand with no side-effects (and be fast!).

I might be asking too much. However, if there was a way in Python to modify the original file by only writing the diffs of two strings (or dicts), that would speed things up considerably. I've briefly looked at `difflib` and `filecmp` and neither seem to do that.

Or there's another solution I'm not seeing?

Comment: A dictionary seems something not unreasonable. Dump it to JSON on file to keep it human-readable, and load if from there to memory when you want to process data. Wrap the main routine in try/except and save the current dictionary if anything happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: How fast does it need to be? Have you looked at using the CDumper under ruamel.yaml/PyYAML?